# Eclipse RunTime NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, eclipse, pydev, noclassdeffounderror

I am having trouble trying to use an imported class from a jar file which is located in the referenced libraries of my project.

So I have a project which has the pydev.jar file in the Referenced Libraries. Pydev.jar contains org.python.pydev.navigator.elements.PythonNode, and I have imported this in one of the Java files. Eclipse does not give an errors when I import and use this in the Java file but when I run the project as an Eclipse application there is a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/python/pydev/navigator/elements/PythonNode exception being thrown.

Code is trying to cast an ISelection to a PythonNode as below:

```
IStructuredSelection sel = (IStructuredSelection) 
                                window.getSelectionService().getSelection();

ArrayList<String> testNames = new ArrayList<String>();
Iterator<?> itr = sel.iterator();

String testName = "";
String testSuite = "";

while(itr.hasNext()) {
    PythonNode selectionElement = (PythonNode) itr.next();

    testName = selectionElement.toString();
    testSuite = selectionElement.pythonFile.toString();

    testNames.add(testSuite + "." + testName);
}
```

If anyone can explain why the Exception is being thrown for the use of the PythonNode class at runtime I would be very appreciative. As far as I can see it is imported correctly as it is visible in the Referenced Libraries.

Comment: Does PythonNode reference other classes in that archive that you haven't included in the classpath?

Comment: I don't know is the honest answer. I was assuming that it would have appeared in the stack trace if it were another class that was not being found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're building either Eclipse RCP or Eclipse plugin. Am I right?

If yes, you should put pydev.jar under plugin dependencies. Go to plugin.xml, Runtime and put pydev.jar in the classpath

Comment: Hi,
How do I add pydev.jar to the classpath? When I select 'Add', only the project folder structure is displayed. How do I add the external JAR?

Comment: you should first copy the .jar to your project structure otherwise Eclipse doesn't know how to pack it together as a plugin.